# How to compute the mean for certain category rows?

Tags: r

Assuming this data:

```
df <- tibble(
word = c("apple", "apple","banana", "pear","pear","A","A","A"), 
i = seq_along(word),year=c(2000,2001,2000,2000,2001,2000,2001,2002)
)
```

I want to calculate the mean of column i for all  words (per year) in column word without A and banana.
and give the name out
the output would be

```
      word       i  year
     <chr>  <int> <dbl>
     1 out      2.5  2000
     2 out      3.5  2001
     3 banana     4  2000
     5 A          7  2000
     8 A          8  2001
     9 A          9  2002
```

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you want, i.e. how do you want to calculate a mean from a word (character)? Where does the „out“ come from, i.e why is there no row for apple and pear, but for A and banana? And your input data has 8 rows, whereas your output appears to be based on 9 rows?

Comment: What is the world in which `out` is the mean of `apple` and `pear`? Please explain as I think it sounds like a nice place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may group by 'year', and the 'word' after `replace`ing the elements that are not 'A', 'banana' with 'out' and get the `mean` of 'i' and order the rows by 'group' (`arrange`) if neccessary

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(year, word = replace(word, !(word %in% c('A', 'banana')), 'out')) %>%
  summarise(i = mean(i), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  arrange(factor(word, levels = c('out', 'banana', 'A'))) %>%
  select(names(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

First we replace all not `banana` and `A` with `out` in an `ifelse` statement, then group and summarise. Finally arrange:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(word = ifelse(word != "banana" & word !="A", "out", word)) %>% 
  group_by(year, word) %>% 
  summarise(mean_i = mean(i)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(word))
```

```
   year word   mean_i
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1  2000 out       2.5
2  2001 out       3.5
3  2000 banana    3  
4  2000 A         6  
5  2001 A         7  
6  2002 A         8
```

Answer (score 2):

**Base R solution**

We first `split` the data by word and, within word, year. Then give us the `mean` of i. Store the mean values of i pertaining to all words but 'A' and 'apple' in `out`. Finally, make a `data.frame` with columns for word, year, and our means and use some `regex` to obtain tidy column names.

```
means <- sapply(split(df, f = ~ df$word + df$year), \(x) mean(x$i))
out <- means[!grepl('^[Aa]', names(means))]
df_new <- data.frame(
  word=gsub('\\.[0-9]*', '', names(out)),
  year=gsub('[^[0-9]]*', '', names(out)),
  mean_i=out
)
rownames(df_new) <- NULL
```

**Output**

```
> df_new
    word year mean_i
1 banana 2000      3
2   pear 2000      4
3 banana 2001    NaN
4   pear 2001      5
5 banana 2002    NaN
6   pear 2002    NaN
```

If you want to omit rows containing missing values of `mean_i`, then you could use something like `df_new[rowSums(apply(df_new, 2, is.na)) < 1, ]`

```
> df_new[rowSums(apply(df_new, 2, is.na)) < 1, ]
    word year mean_i
1 banana 2000      3
2   pear 2000      4
4   pear 2001      5
```

Note: use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` if you use a version of R <4.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# assign name "mean" to the new column with average (mean) values
> dt[!(word %in% c('banana', 'A') ), .(mean = mean(i)), by = .(year, word)]
   year  word mean
1: 2000 apple    1
2: 2001 apple    2
3: 2000  pear    4
4: 2001  pear    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!(word %in% c('A', 'banana'))) %>%
  group_by(year, word) %>%
  summarize(Mean =mean(i))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   year [2]
   year word   Mean
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1  2000 apple     1
2  2000 pear      4
3  2001 apple     2
4  2001 pear      5
```

Update:
Inspired by akrun I slightly improved the filter.